# Python Retrieving Information from an SQLite3 Database

Tags: python, database, sqlite

```
import sqlite3

Class = str(input("Which class are you in? A) 11A B) 11B C) 11C"))
f_name = str(input("What is your first name?"))
s_name = str(input("What is your surname?"))
h_score = "8"
a_score = "7"
t_taken = "3"

if Class == "11A" or "11a":
    counter = 0
    while counter < 1:
        db_students = sqlite3.connect('//persian/controlledassessment$/work/11 C CS/10BakeEd/Python/Task 2/db_Students.db')
        c=db_students.cursor()
        c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ClassA
         (student_firstname text,
        student_surname text,
        h_score number,
        a_score number,
        t_taken number,
        Class text)
        ''')
        c.execute('''INSERT INTO ClassA
         VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)''',(f_name, s_name, h_score, a_score, t_taken, Class))
        db_students.commit()
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM ClassA")
        fetchall=c.fetchall() 
        print(fetchall)
        db_students.close()
        counter = counter + 1





elif Class == "11B" or "11b":
    print()

elif Class == "11C" or "11c":
    print()

else:    
    print("")
```

This is my code at the moment and some of the variables at the are placeholders. What I want to do is pull information out of the database that I have created and assign it to a variables so that I can use them in calculations such as averages.

Comment: Probably unrelated: `if Class == "11A" or "11a":` does not do what you think it does. You want to use `if Class in ("11A", "11a"):` or `if Class.lower() == "11a":`. Also, no need to call `str()` on a result from `input()`.

Answer (score 0):

`fetchall()` returns a list of rows, where each row is a tuple containing (in this case) six values.

You could go through this list, but unless you need to do random accesses to all rows, it is a better idea to use the cursor as an iterator:

```
c.execute(...)
for row in c:
    print(c[0])    # prints all first names
else:
    pass           # no rows found
```

If you want to compute averages, it would be a better idea to do this directly in SQL:

```
c.execute("SELECT AVG(h_score), AVG(a_score) FROM ClassA WHERE Class LIKE '11a'")
avg_h, avg_a = c.fetch()
```